# Show favourites first in separate section in a table view

Tags: objective-c

I'm making an app where the user can favourite different items in the detail view.

I have a table view where I show all the items, and I want to show the favourites in a separate section in that same table view. Any ideas how to do this?

At this moment I save all the favourites in a NSMutableArray called favouriteItems.

I guess I have to remove the favourite objects from the original array.
But can I fill the tableview with two arrays?
One array with the favourite in the first section and the rest in the second section

Comment: So what have you tried so far? How do you "know" which object is a favorite? Is it displaying two arrays in two sections or splitting one array into two that is holding you back? (Don't answer "both")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can. You just need 2 sections in your table view.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return normalItems.count;
            break;
        case 1:
            return favouriteItems.count;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return @"Normal Items";
            break;
        case 1:
            return @"Favorite Items";
        default:
            break;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";

    CeldaCell *cell = (CeldaCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CeldaCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = [normalItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            break;
        case 1:
                        cell.textLabel.text = [favouriteItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've made some changes in my app, and I now only have only one array with all the recipes, and sort them with sortUsingComparator so the favourites are displayed first. I have a model object called Item with a BOOL called isFavourite. Can I put all the items with isFavourite = YES in one section and everyone else in another?

Comment: It will probably be more efficient to use 2 arrays. But you can do it the way you say too. You just have to have 2 sections and count the number of favorites and no favorites in the correspondent UITableViewDatasource method. I could post some code, but is much better if you try and then come back with any doubts.

Comment: Im almost there. When I add a favourite it moves to the right section, but in the original section it is replaced by an empty cell with a empty Label, and when I click on the row the detailview of the item that I favourited shows up.

In numberOfRowsInSection I loop through all my items, and have two integers which increases if item.isFavourite == 1. In cellForRowAtIndexPath I also check if item.isFavourite = 1 or 0. And  I set cell.textlabel = item.title in my if statement.

Comment: So my problem is: When I add a favourite why is it replaced by an empty cell? Well it's not empty because it has the connection to the item that i moved to the favourite section.

Comment: And also: the last item of my other objects is removed (because my integer decreases ofc)

Comment: It's really hard to help you without seeing the new code. Please, create another question.